# Dynamics view values in field on select record in Php

Tags: php, select, drop-down-menu

I want view a price values in a field when select a record from dropdown list.

This is the dropdown list code with php code inside:

```
                    <select name="product_id[]" class="form-control">
                        <?php
                        include("connect.php");
                            $query = "
                        SELECT *
                          FROM tbl_product ORDER BY product_desc ASC
                         ";
                            $result = mysql_query($query);
                            while ($record = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                            echo "
                                <option value=\"$record[product_id]\">$record[product_cod] $record[product_desc]</option>";
                            }
                        ?>
                    </select> <input type="text" name="product_price[]" size="6">
```

In to the specific case: in dropdown list I have 3 records products:
1 milk 3euro
2 wather 1euro
3 caffee 4euro

For example, when select the second record, in the filed price how to put the 4euros values?

Thanks

Comment: What do you actually want to do? Where's your `price field` ?

Comment: I add the fileld in the example script.
<input type="text" name="product_price[]" size="6">

I want view the price of product selected in the filed product_price

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you could try using something like this. My code uses `ajax` to get the price of the `product_id` we got from `select`.

```
<?php
include("connect.php");
$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_product ORDER BY product_desc ASC";
$result = mysql_query($query);
?>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="product_id[]" class="form-control">
<?php
while ($record = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
   ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $record['product_id']; ?>"><?php echo $record['product_cod'] . " " . $record['product_desc']; ?></option>
<?php
}
?>
</select> <input type="text" id="input_price" name="product_price[]" size="6" value="">
<script>

$( "select" )
  .change(function () {
    var val = $( "select option:selected").val();
    //$('#input_price').val(val);
    $.ajax({

    url : 'ajax_getprice.php',
    type : 'GET',
    data : {
        'product_id' : val
    },
    dataType:'json',
    success : function(data) {              
        $('#input_price').val(data);
    },
    error : function(request,error)
    {
        alert("Request: "+JSON.stringify(request));
    }
});
  })
  .change();

</script>
```

**ajax_priceget.php**

```
<?php

$productid = $_GET['product_id']; //you have the product id now
//now write a query to select the price of the product using the product id and echo the price

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Frankie, if the price field is separetly shown somewhere then there are two ways by which you can perform this,
**1-** Use jquery to get the prices, in order to do it through jquery you need to place the prices of the records in their values and then to use $('.product_id[]').val(); to get the price of the selected record.
**2-** Second way is to use the ajax for that purpose if you have stored item's prices in the databse then you need to hit the database by sitting at the front end at the onChange's jquery method you need to get ajax response regarding the prices against the product id,s and then to display at any posisiton you want to.